# Remove pgadmin 4 from Windows

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am using pgadmin 4.1.2 and it is extremely slow. I installed pgadmin 3 and it works like a charm.
How do I remove pgadmin 4 from my Windows 2008 R2 machine?

Kr
A.H.

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: It came with the postgres server installation

Comment: I don't think there is a way to uninstalled it individually,  you can try deleting 'pgAdmin4' folder under C:\\PorgramFiles\\PostgreSQL\

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing. It feels like pgAdmin 4 has a ways to go before it catches up with pgAdmin 3 regarding basic functionality and responsiveness.

Comment: Definitely has a way to go even being usable

Comment: I am definetly not going to complain ever again about pgAdmin 3. Now it feels lightning fast. And its crashing is just some minor nuissance compared to pgAdmin 4.

Comment: pgAdmin 4 uses HTML, CSS, JavaScript and "Frameworks" (jQuery, Bootstrap) as part of their technology stack. It's not surprising that this turns out to be inadequate. On my workstation it is not just slow but also takes > 10 times more memory than pgAdmin 3.

Comment: The latest version 4 v3.0 runs in browser and much faster.

Answer (score 24):

Tested today by me...

As the other answers says, pgAdmin, if installed independently of postgres, have it own uninstall under windows apps.

But if the pgAdmin was installed with postgres installation, my case, it do not have it own uninstall, but is possible to uninstall it with postgres uninstall.

At the start of the uninstallation, simply select "Individual components", pgAdmin 4 and continue. Done.

Hope it helps someone with the same problem.

Update: Aparently, as @Nux pointed out, the firsts versions of pgAdmin 4 didn't have this option.

Comment: There is no option like that for PostgreSQL 9.6 which comes with PgAdmin 4 v1. See: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxoy3bATeZooGFQBnAa280qESCCn3WJcewUhqx7prL1_c2Q%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: This solution worked with PostgreSQL 15 on Windows 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to pgAdmin 4 installation folder and under version folder there's an uninstall executable file. After installation you can remove the pdAdmin 4 and the rest of the files.

Comment: Are you sure? In my pgAdmin 4 folder is only "bin", "docs", "venv" and "web". No uninstall executable.

Comment: go to Programs & Features >> PostgreSQL (xx) >> uninstall >> choose to uninstall Individual Components >> select pgAdmin (xx)

Answer (score 1):

You can click on "Windows Button" then type: appwiz.cpl the interface of installing and modifying installed programs will appear. Scroll to PostgreSQL[version installed number] and double click on it. You choose the second option (indivdual components) and by next you check the checkbox for pgadmin4. let it go until the end and you will be Ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Good news, PgAdmin 4 in version 2.1 can be uninstalled, as other Windows apps.

It is still much slower then PgAdmin 3...

Comment: There is an option like that but it doesn't work. Or at least it did not unistall PgAdmin v4 on my Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can go the location where you install PostgreSQL. Eg C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL then delete it.

Answer (score -1):

from a windows you can go to the directory location and inside there is a  .exe file for uninstallation. You simply run it and done ! It's just worked for me.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50093891/2227743).