# Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4... while opening pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have installed postgreSQL 14 on windows 10 and after opening pgAdmin this inscription "Loading pdAdmin4..." lasts forever

[image: this is a picture of pgAdmin]

I tried to change version of postgres to 15, but it didn't help
I tried to add `Content Type=text/javascript` and `ContentType=text/javascript` to Regedit > `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js`. That did not solve the issue.

Comment: pgAdmin4 != Postgres. pgAdmin4 is just a GUI client, you do not have to reinstall/update the Postgres server to deal with its issues.

Comment: okey, but how can I solve this problem with constant loading?

Comment: File an [issue](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/issues/). Use another client say `psql`.

Comment: I suppose you can try reinstalling pgAdmin

Comment: Still an open issue, better to downgrade https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6597

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like this is an issue in pgAdmin V7.4 because a lot of people are facing the same problem.

So you can downgrade to V7.3 until this issue is resolved.

You can download it from this link: [PgAdmin Download link](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/)

Answer (score 6):

1. Install an older version (like v.7.3), from here: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/
2. Download (not install yet) the latest version of Postgres SQL from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
3. Now, while installing Postgres uncheck: "pgAdmin 4", when asked to select the components
4. Start the "pgAdmin 4" installed in step 1
5. If you have an error, try again to launch the v.7.3 as Administrator.
6. Login to the server

Answer (score 4):

If you install **PgAdmin4 v7.4** from the Postgres installation, uninstall using the **Postgres uninstall**. Then download it independently from the website https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to solve without downgrade by download pgAdmin 7.4 at [PgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/) and replace the original pgAdmin 7.4 in your PC with that one, you have to uninstall the original first follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669577/remove-pgadmin-4-from-windows/50093891#comment116247438_50093891)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar loading issues twice, the third time I ran the tool as "run as administrator ", it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing pgAdmin via the postgresql-15.3-3-windows-x64 installer.

Solution:

- uninstall PostgreSQL;
- reinstall PostgreSQL but in the components selection, uncheck PG Admin;
- download pgAdmin from https://www.pgadmin.org/download/ and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the "pgAdmin 4 v7.4 loading forever" problem; I solved by uninstalling PostgreSQL *and you have to delete all the PostgreSQL folders on the C: drive (if you have a prior PostgreSQL installation)*, then download a fresh PostgreSQL 14 and install that, then download pgAdmin 4 v7.3 and install that. Then postgres 14 came up immediately.